# How to check if one of my app is installed in IOS device using corona sdk

Tags: ios, coronasdk, url-scheme

How am I going to get a returned value that allows me to know whether my app was installed in IOS. In android, we can use "android.app.icon://my.package.name" by placing it in a display.newImage if it is not a nil value then I know one of my app was installed. We can't use that in an IOS device. I searched a link about using a url scheme

http://coronalabs.com/blog/2011/12/22/using-app-url-schemes-in-ios/

But the information was not that clear enough for me to understand and was not detailed at all. Is there another way to do it? I want to know the code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The system.openURL() will return false if it can't open your app using a URL Scheme.

Comment: Can you show me an example of that, like what value can be place on the URL Scheme? Can it be a packagename? app name? or something else?

Comment: For iOS, the URL scheme is defined in  your build.settings.  See: http://coronalabs.com/blog/2011/12/22/using-app-url-schemes-in-ios/

For Android, there is discussion on this in this forum thread: http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/37105-handling-url-scheme-on-android/

Comment: You just re-type the link